# npm install fails - make fails

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, cloud9-ide

I am trying to run `npm install` in the Cloud9 IDE environment to update my drivers, etc. When I run, I get the following output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkrb5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgssapi_krb5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Release/obj.target/kerberos.node] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/kerberos/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-    gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.14.13-c9
gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

My application will not run on Heroku since the latest update to MongoLab and I am attempting to update packages to remedy that problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see `ld` couldn't find `krb5` and `gssapi_krb5` libraries.
Installing `libkrb5-dev` and `libgssapi-krb5-2` and other dependencies would resolve your problem